# How do I drop Postgres column with name ["app_id"]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres column with the column name `["app_id"]` (yes with a `[` and `"`). I accidentally created it and want to drop it.

Yet I tried to drop it but can't seem to get it to work.
I've tried:

```
alter table articles drop column '["app_id"]';
alter table articles drop column ["app_id"];
alter table articles drop column [""app_id""];
```

What's the DROP statement like for this column?

Answer (score 5):

Wrap it in double quotes while escaping (by doubling) the inside double quotes

```
alter table articles drop column "[""app_id""]";
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS